# opengl rotating an object individually with glm

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation, glm-math

I have an object that I need to rotate. For some reason known only to the computer my entire scene gets rotated, that is all the objects get rotated as a group. Please note that all the objects are from the same class. I wanted to rotate these objects individually in the same time. I can't post all the code but here are the relevant parts. I'll add more code if asked to.
This is where I periodically update the rotation angle:

```
void Model::Update( float dt ) {    
    mRotationAngleInDegrees += dt;
}
```

This is where i calculate the transform matrix:

```
mat4 Model::GetWorldMatrix() const {
    mat4 worldMatrix( 1.0f );
    worldMatrix = glm::translate( worldMatrix, position );
    worldMatrix = glm::rotate( worldMatrix, mRotationAngleInDegrees, vec3( 0, 0, 1 ) );
    return worldMatrix;
}
```

This is where I paint the model:

```
void Model::Draw() {

    GLuint WorldMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(Renderer::getShaderID(), "WorldTransform"); 
    glUniformMatrix4fv(WorldMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &GetWorldMatrix()[0][0]);

    //vertex buffer code here

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 9);

    //some more cleanup code here
}
```

And here is the relevant code in main:

```
for( vector<Model>::iterator it = grass.begin(); it != grass.end(); ++it ) {
    it->Update(dt);
    it->Draw();
}
```

Can anyone see what's the problem?

Comment: Since you are changing the `ModelView` matrix then the rotation applies to the whole model. You need to restore the matrix to its prior state when you are going to draw the rest of the scene. P.S Send my regards to Prince Vlad :)

Comment: Thank you Forty2 for helping. I am afraid that is not the problem because even when I generate a single object it gets rotated in a big circle. I wanted it to rotate locally in the same place (that's why i am translating the matrix to the position of the object). I also don't store that matrix anywhere, so I can't revert it back to its original state. As for Prince Vlad, I am him. I just refused to die when they tried to kill me with garlic. It's just a harmless vegetable.

Comment: just want to add that in function Draw that is the only place I use the function GetWorldMatrix()

Comment: I think I realized what you mean. I've added this line of code to function GetWorldMatrix(): `worldMatrix = glm::translate( worldMatrix, -position );` and now most objects rotate correctly, but some still rotate in big circles.

Comment: I finally got it right. The objects that did not behave were rotated elsewhere. Thank you 40two. Your hint put me on the right path. Do you care to write an answer so i can make it a solution? Or should i delete this question?

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to address your comments. You should answer your question so in the future someone that would have the same problem would benefit from your answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in function `GetWorldMatrix()` after rotating I was supposed to translate the model matrix back to the original location. That is necessary because the local rotation must follow these steps (in this strict order):

1. translate from the original point to the anchor of rotation
2. rotate
3. translate back to the original point

So I added this line:

```
worldMatrix = glm::translate( worldMatrix, -position );
```

The function now looks like this:

```
mat4 Model::GetWorldMatrix() const {
    mat4 worldMatrix( 1.0f );
    worldMatrix = glm::translate( worldMatrix, position );
    worldMatrix = glm::rotate( worldMatrix, mRotationAngleInDegrees, vec3( 0, 0, 1 ) );
    worldMatrix = glm::translate( worldMatrix, -position );
    return worldMatrix;
}
```

Thank you, 40two, for the great hint.